# Why does the clock think he's in Detroit?

Tags: geolocation, clock

We have brand new phones, and my husband's HTC Evo Shift 4G clock app seems to think he's in Detroit. He isn't. We've never even been to Michigan, which is probably our loss, I'm sure Michigan is beautiful, but the point is that it isn't like we've got a billing address in Detroit or a Detroit area code. The map knows where we are, but the clock shows his "current location" as Detroit. I can't find a way to change that in the clock settings.

We've tried with `Settings > Date & time settings` on  both "Automatic" and not. I even rebooted after enabling automatic date/time. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I don't suppose it's a Detroit area code/exchange, is it?

Comment: Under `Settings | Date & time settings` is "Automatic" checked?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Do you want it to auto-update, or are you fine with specifying a location manually on the widget ? How far are you located from Detroit ?

Comment: We're about 700 miles from Detroit. I did specify a location manually but can't seem to delete Detroit. Now it shows New York as the "home" location and Detroit as the "current" location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the HTC Sense clock widget that appears on the Home screen?  It looks like this:

[image: Clock Widget]

If so, it's important to note that the location listed there is indicating what location the **weather** refers to, not the *time*.  [HTC's support site](http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?id=23160&type=1&p_id=391) has an explanation of how to work with the widget, including editing settings.

It sounds like you added a new location to the weather configuration (which is why it separates it into "Home" and "Current location"), but it's still showing some other, non-current, and non-"Home" weather forecast.  For that, you'll want to read [Checking weather](http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?id=23161&type=1&p_id=391), also on HTC's support website.  It explains how to add new cities to the list, how to rearrange the order of the cities (e.g., so that the *important* one shows up first), and most important: how to *delete* one ;)

Don't worry about it being for the HTC Desire S -- both phones run Android with HTC Sense, so the steps will be the same for both.

Comment: Bingo. I won't get into how illogical and exasperating that was.